# Makefile generator creates two files

Tags: makefile

I have a generator program that creates two version files, say `ver.h` and `ver.cpp`. My ultimate build target depends on both of these files, and the rule for building both is that one program. If I did this:

```
build : ver.h ver.cpp

ver.h ver.cpp :
    ./gen/version/program
```

then a parallel build could run `program` twice, which, while not *bad* is just excessive. I figure I could have them both depend on a phony target:

```
ver.h ver.cpp : do-version-impl

do-version-impl:
    ./gen/version/program

.PHONY : do-version-impl
```

Is that the best way to do this? It smells a little funny to have to introduce a phony rule to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the phony target as the prerequisite is a bad idea.  `program` will be run even if `ver.*` files exist, which is a false positive error.

More subtly, GNU Make is only guaranteed to update its file timestamp, if that file is a target of a rule with a recipe. So here, even though `program` is always run, anything that in turn depends on `ver.*` files might not get updated at all!

In my opinion it is best to not make up unnatural patterns for each target, but instead, go explicit:

There is a "main" file that you are generating, that is `ver.cpp`.  Use the "no-op" recipe `;` for the other one, which can be put on the same line like this:

```
ver.h: ver.cpp ;
ver.cpp: Makefile
    ./gen/version/program
```

This method starts with what you wrote, but adds the very important `;`.

If you did not have a natural candidate for the "main" file, then in my opinion it is best to use a "sentinel":

```
ver.h ver.cpp: sentinel ;

sentinel: Makefile
    ./gen/version/program
    touch $@
```

Again, this method is similar to one of your methods, but very importantly, does not use a phony, but a real file.

Comment: Does `ver.%: Makefile` prevent the generation from being run twice? The other solutions do and are quite likely preferable to my hack of a solution though.

Comment: What does the semicolon do, as opposed to just having nothing between the `ver.h: ver.cpp` line and the `ver.cpp: Makefile` one?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes it is the same argument as you quoted, for pattern rules, the default behaviour is to run the recipe once then retake the timestamp of other targets

Comment: @Barry the semicolon is the "no-op" recipe.  It is necessary so that Make is guaranteed to retake the timestamp of the targets.  I wrote about this in my answer above.

Comment: Why would make think that `ver.h` and `ver.cpp` are both made by `ver.%` at the same time? Why wouldn't it run it twice? The same as it does for `%.o` when building `foo.o` and `bar.o`? (If different targets depend on `ver.h` and `ver.cpp` for instance and running with `-j`.)

Comment: @EtanReisner  well is it not what you quoted yourself from the manual in your answer?  Both `ver.h` and `ver.cpp` are matched by the same pattern rule, with the same prerequisites.  Therefore by the manual, the rule's recipe will be run once, and Make will update its timestamps for both targets.

Comment: Two patterns in the same target is a special case. That's why it has its own paragraph and says "Unlike the normal case".

Comment: @EtanReisner oh I see what you mean, finally.  Thank you for being patient with me.  Well, my reading of the fragment "pattern rules may have more than one target (...) this does not act as many different rules", is that, if in the course of finding rules for targets, more than one target is found the same pattern rule with the same prerequisites and the same recipe (so in particular the recipe does not depend on the target itself), then, the recipe is executed only once.  This reading is supported by the empirical evidence in this case. I agree the manual is not completely clear though.

Comment: @EtanReisner I understand that you are reading this fragment to mean, "there are multiple words listed as targets".  I would not expect that to matter, because then, one could just repeat the same thing:  `ver.% ver.%: Makefile`  , and then magically the Makefile would work.  It would be silly IMO to require the user to repeat words to achieve some aim.  Although, some natural languages, use repetition to mean "more" :)

Comment: Actually, empirically (at least with make 3.81) what we are discussing does (under `-j`) run the same command more than once. See https://gist.github.com/deryni/ba329ef8e4fbdd358692 And `ver.% ver.%: Makefile` doesn't help (which makes sense since those patterns likely collapse).

Comment: @EtanReisner hmm, this is baffling, it may be that I got lucky my answer seems to work, but really it does not.  Don't have time at the moment but will experiment with this later this eve.  Thank you for bringing this stuff up.

Comment: It does work if you win the race. Remove the `sleep` in my example and it'll work some of the time (even much of the time).

Comment: @EtanReisner OK I experimented some and my reading is incorrect, and my first answer consequently was incorrect too.  I deleted it. Thank you for pointing this.  As best I can tell, the manual is not clear.  It should probably clarify "if there are multiple targets and each matches a different pattern and only that pattern, then the rule will be executed once".  Otherwise, depending on parallelism, the behaviour is indeterminate.

Comment: Clarification certainly wouldn't hurt but I think in that context 'targets' fairly clearly means entries on the line and not files that match the pattern. But that certainly isn't a necessary reading. The support in make for multiple files being generated by a single rule is just not very good unfortunately.

Comment: @EtanReisner not enough to have multiple and even different entries on the line.  The condition I wrote above seems sufficient and makes sense IMO from the spirit of the current paragraph in the manual.  Anything less than that, does not work.   I checked this experimentally.

Answer (score 1):

See [10.5.1 Introduction to Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) specifically the last paragraph:

> 10.5.1 Introduction to Pattern Rules
>
> ...
>
> A pattern rule need not have any prerequisites that contain ‘%’, or in fact any prerequisites at all. Such a rule is effectively a general wildcard. It provides a way to make any file that matches the target pattern. See Last Resort.
>
> ...
>
> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets. When searching for a pattern rule to match a target, the target patterns of a rule other than the one that matches the target in need of a rule are incidental: make worries only about giving a recipe and prerequisites to the file presently in question. However, when this file’s recipe is run, the other targets are marked as having been updated themselves.

So you could use something like this:

```
v%r.h v%r.cpp:
        ./gen/version/program
```

I believe you need that odd patterning to have make consider the pattern to match (I don't believe it will match `%` against an empty string as `ver%.h ver%.cpp` would need). (I can't find reference to this in the manual at the moment though.)

Comment: You are right in that the empty string doesn't work, I'd have to do something like `ve%.h ve%.cpp`. Do you think it's better to do that or something else I've just come up with... have `ver.h : ver.cpp` and have the rule for building `ver.cpp` be the program?

Comment: @Barry Honestly not sure. Probably better to go this way but I'm not sure there are any issues with the staged route (but I'd have to think about it more to convince myself of that).

Comment: @EtanReisner I have to criticize this answer.  The implicit rules are meant for natural patterns, not patterns made up solely for the purpose of avoiding an explicit target. What if there is another file `verbose.h` that happens to appear during the course of the build.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Your latter two answers (one of which the OP suggested in his comment and I hesitated to suggest because I hadn't reasoned it all through) are quite likely better than this hack. This was mostly to introduce the idea here and less to give it real validation. The fact that GNU Make supports this is nice but it does have its drawbacks. I think someone proposed a more explicit syntax for this on the mailing list recently.

Comment: @EtanReisner  yes OP had it suggested, but, without `;` which is crucial