# Makefile - Dependency checking/command running order

Tags: makefile

I have made a makefile to compile a series of fortran modules. My idea was to write so that make checks if the .o file exists in the folder ../obj and if the .mod file exists in the folder ../mod, and if ANY of those is missing, the module is recompiled and the files are stored in those respective folders. The code is the following:

```
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#
# SOURCES AND PATHS
#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
MODPATH = ../mod
OBJPATH = ../obj
SRCS    = $(wildcard *.f)
OBJS    = $(SRCS:%.f=%.o)
MODS    = $(SRCS:%.f=%.mod)
#
#
# COMPILING ORDERS
#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
FC      = ifort
FFLAGS  = -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module $(MODPATH)

all : objects modules
objects : $(OBJS:%.o=$(OBJPATH)/%.o)
modules : $(MODS:%.mod=$(MODPATH)/%.mod)

$(OBJPATH)/%.o   : %.f ../obj
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
../obj:
        mkdir ../obj

$(MODPATH)/%.mod : %.f ../mod
        $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $< -o $(@:$(MODPATH)/%.mod=$(OBJPATH)/%.o)
../mod:
        mkdir ../mod
#
#
# CLEAN
#--------------------------------------------------------------------#
.PHONY: clean
clean :
        rm -f $(OBJS:%.o=$(OBJPATH)/%.o) $(MODS:%.mod=$(MODPATH)/%.mod)
#
#%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%#
```

It apparently works in the sense that it does what I have described; however, it has a behavior I don't fully understand. For when I make after a make clean, it compiles some of the modules twice and some once:

```
ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module ../mod -c garcha_mod.f -o ../obj/garcha_mod.o
ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module ../mod -c liokeys.f -o ../obj/liokeys.o
ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module ../mod -c sysdata.f -o ../obj/sysdata.o
ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module ../mod -c garcha_mod.f -o ../obj/garcha_mod.o
ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module ../mod -c liokeys.f -o ../obj/liokeys.o
```

(1) Why do some modules compile twice? When it compiles either because the .o or .mod is missing, the command creates both files so when it checks for the other it should notices it has already been done.
(2) Why does it compile some modules twice but then some others only once? I don't notice any difference in how the makefile is doing to those modules.

Comment: You want to set the directories as order-only prerequisites `| ../mod` and `| ../obj` to avoid them contributing to the need to rebuild the target.

Comment: You also can't reliably wildcard on files that may not exist if you want to have make use them as targets or prerequisites. The general idea is to wildcard on *sources* and then build the target patterns from those.

Comment: To answer your first (and probably second) question you should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365859/makefile-generator-creates-two-files/27394953) and the many back and forth comments on Mark Galeck's answer.

Comment: Ok; thanks, I will check that other question. I don't understand the part about wildcarding though; Am I not doing what you said? (wildcarding on sources and building the target patterns from those: I wildcarded on the .f)

Comment: Oh, you are, sorry, somehow I misread that.

Comment: You don't need (and probably don't want) the `objects` and `modules` phony targets either. And if you aren't going to have anything list the `.mod` files (or the `.o` files) as a set as prerequisites you can just leave one of those lists out entirely.

Comment: @Nordico The immediate comment I have is, IMHO using % and - characters for comment separation is a bad idea, because they have meaning inside makefiles.  Very jarring to the eye and does not at all accomplish the intended visual separation.  Stick with `###...`.  That's my opinion.

Comment: @Nordico I realize what I said is of no use to you, sorry.  I will give you a more useful answer in a moment :)

Comment: @Nordico Etan's first comment is the correct answer.  You have indeterminate rebuild behaviour, because you have depended objects on changes to their directory, so when the directory changes, because a new object has appeared, all objects rebuild again.

Comment: @EtanReisner I disagree with wildcard on _sources_ _in general_ as well.  If he deletes a source file, `all` will not rebuild.  Here it does not matter, but in general, it would matter.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies! @MarkGaleck One doubt regarding the explicit sources. If I delete a file, I would probably also want to take it out from the sources list; wouldn't this be the same situation as wildcardign and hence result in `all` not rebuilding? Unless I first delete the file, then recompile, and then modify the explicit list of files. But remembering this order does not seem that much simpler than remembering to touch something or make clean before compiling when I delete I file (specially since it seems easy to notice if you forget and make does nothing).

Comment: @Nordico  no it would not be the same.  If you wildcard sources, and you delete a source, nothing will change as far as GNU Make is concerned.  There would be no rebuild.  You may have a library for example, made up from all the objects - the library won't change.  If you don't wildcard, but list explicitly _and_ depend the library on the Makefile (see in my answer, I depend everything on the Makefile itself), only then, will the deletion of a source not cause problems.

Comment: OH, I see; I had noticed that you included Makefile in the dependencies but I didn't understand why was that. Now I do.

Comment: @Nordico  well, depending on the Makefile, is not only because of that.  One should always depend all non-trivial rules, on the Makefiles.  If the recipe does not use any variables, then just on the Makefile in which it is - that's because change in the Makefile, could .  If it does use variables, then potentially, all makefiles: $(MAKEFILE_LIST).  That's because the change in Makefile(s) could potentially affect the recipe and hence the target.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me, but your makefile is a bit of a mess.  So I rewrote it with good practices and all the problems disappear.  Both `objects` and `modules` are strictly speaking, not needed, but perhaps you need them elsewhere if you expand your makefile, so I included them.

Wildcarding sources is bad idea all around.  See my comment above.  List files explicitly - it is healthy for you! :)

```
MODPATH := ../mod
OBJPATH := ../obj

SRCS    := \
    garcha_mod.f \
    liokeys.f \
    sysdata.f \

.PHONY: all  objects modules
all : objects modules

objects : $(SRCS:%.f=$(OBJPATH)/%.o)
modules : $(SRCS:%.f=$(MODPATH)/%.mod)

$(OBJPATH)/%.o : $(MODPATH)/%.mod ;

.SECONDARY: %/.
%/.: Makefile
    mkdir -p $*

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(MODPATH)/%.mod : %.f Makefile | $$(@D)/. $(OBJPATH)/.
    ifort -g -O3 -c -cpp -Dpack -fPIC -module $(@D) -o $(OBJPATH)/$*.o

clean: 
    rm -rf $(MODPATH)
    rm -rf $(OBJPATH)
```

There is a subtle issue here.

If the user deleted only the `.o` file, it would be a problem. One solves this by telling the user, to not gratuitously delete files without knowing what they are doing.  They have to use `make clean`, or better yet, do not delete anything at any time, because with a properly constructed makefile, there is no need.

Also one needs to observe, by careful reading of GNU Make rules concerning interruptions, that killing a recipe in progress, cannot result in `.mod` file being present but `.o` being absent.

This is in fact, why I order the "clean" recipe this way. It's important to first delete `$(MODPATH)` then `$(OBJPATH)`.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! Yeah, it doesn't surprise me that it is a mess. heh. Its my first attempt at a "serious" makefile. As a matter of fact, I am not that familiar with the basis of how make works (timestamps and what else there might be), and the rules/dependencies/functions for `.SECONDARY`,`.SECONDEXPANSION` and `$(MODPATH)/%.mod` are just beyond my grasp right now, but I will try to read more in order to fully understand this post and the one Etan quoted before.

Comment: One question though: I can't delete the whole `$(MODPATH)` and `$(OBJPATH)` because this modules are part of a larger library, and other parts also put compiled files in those places. My plan was to have the overall makefile enter the folder of this makefile and call make. Is this a bad practice? It just seemed simpler to me if each part of the lib that could be considered "separate" from the rest had its own makefile (specially the modules).

Comment: @Nordico  you can have a "separate" Makefile, if that part of the build is really "separate", that means, it is completely self-contained, it does not use any of your sources from outside itself, or any other files built up from sources, from outside itself.  In other words, if you could delete all other sources, this part of the build would still work.  Otherwise, don't use "recursive" Make.  See the classic papers "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" and another one at http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html

Comment: @Nordico  if during the course of the build, `$(MODPATH)` and `$(OBJPATH)` directories are created, then they must be deleted during `make clean`.

Comment: @Nordico actually, if this is your first real makefile attempt, you are doing extremely well!  Your makefile was certainly much better than _my_ first attempt :)

Comment: haha, thanks. I did one before but for a program of my own which had like 3 source files; this is for a part in a shared project and is a bit more complex. After reading the quoted sources I think I will try to modify the "main" makefile. I have a question before that: I don't understand the way the recursive make paper deals with dependencies with a script; is that only for c case and not so good for fortran? It also isn't all that clear to me from the paper how should I organize the information in the main makefile and the .mk files to be included; is there another source explaining that?

Comment: @Nordico you are talking about a non-recursive paper...  Well, that is part of the problem with the "correct" approach - the non-recusive approach.  It is not obvious to implement, not for beginners.  The best I can advise you, is to read this paper carefully, to death, several times, and start on something small and carefully make sure that it all works.  I did implement this paper twice for large scale corporate environment, and in each case, it was not a trivial thing.

Comment: @Nordico as I remember, in the paper, there is the main Makefile, and each directory has a fragment .mk.  there is nothing c-specific there and not-fortran specific.  What I did, is for each directory fragment, there is a variable $(D) which is equal to the path to that directory.  The make fragment may include similar fragments in subdirs. Then, inside a subdirectory fragment $(D) becomes that directory, and so forth.  You are implementing a directory stack, as you go down, you are putting new directories on the stack, as you come back up, you remove.  $(D) is always the top of the stack.

Comment: @Nordico, if you don't want to go through this, partitioning makefile fragments into directories and recursively including them all in the top makefile, then, have one big makefile on top (which may include others also at the top level).  Yes it will be big and hard to manage.  But that is the only alternative if you don't want to be correct and fancy.  Recursive Make is just hopeless, don't even think about it.

Comment: I do want to use the "fancy" way. I've tried reading it a few time; now I'm trying to first read fully the GNUmake manual to better understand the paper. I still struggle to understand both the purpose of the $(D) directory variable and how it actually works (since make first reads the whole makefile, during the actual execution of rules the variables like $(D) should always have the last value assigned to them in the makefile with all it's includes; is this not so?)

Comment: The C specific part I was talking about was that of the "gcc -MM" in the depend.sh; I don't know how to output rules for make with fortran compilers (fortran does not use headers, but there is an analogous dependency when using modules). If there was not, that would mean to forget about the .d files altogether and just have one .mk including the proper dependencies between all the files? Or still have the .d individual files but make them manually?

Comment: Oh, also: my rules now would have to depend upon all makefile included files also, right?

Comment: @Nordico  yes all targets should in general depend on at least the makefile fragment they are in, and if the recipe has variables evaluated, then all makefiles included period.  As for the Emile Van Bergen paper, it's all there.  When I implement it, yes I change things, because I like it differently, but you don't have to.  Everything is in that paper.  Read it, consult the manual for clarification, and repeat.  Until it all makes sense.  I know, for a newbie, it is going to be difficult, but there is no other way.

Comment: @Nordico for Fortran compiler, or any other tool that uses not just files that are mentioned on its command line, but some "hidden" files, you must list the hidden files yourself, or use your own tool to generate their listing. That or, use Electric Cloud Accelerator - it is a GNU-Make compatible high-performance Make that has powerful features, such as automatic dependency generation, for any tool or compiler.