# Makefile dependencies on multiple files

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies

I have created a Makefile for unit tests which uses GCC with arguments to create profiling files (gcno) during compiling. Here's a similified part of it where compiling and linking takes place:

```
UTEXE        = $(UTOBJSDIR)\$(UTUNIT).exe
UTOBJS       = $(UTUUTSRC:.c=.o) $(UTUTSRC:.c=.o) $(UTCSRC:.c=.o)
UTOBJSFULL   = $(addprefix $(UTOBJSDIR)\,$(UTOBJS))
UTOBJSGCNO   = $(addprefix $(UTOBJSDIR)\,$(UTOBJS:.o=.gcno))

$(UTOBJS): %.o: %.c $(UTMAKEDEP)
    $(call report,Compiling $(*F).c)
    $(MKDEP) $(MKDFLAGS) -o.o -f$(UTOBJSDIR)\$(*F).dep $(subst /,\,$<)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(subst /,\,$<) -o $(UTOBJSDIR)/$@

$(UTOBJSGCNO): $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP)

utbuild: $(UTEXE) $(UTOBJSGCNO) $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP)

$(UTEXE): $(UTOBJSGCNO) $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP)
    $(call report,Linking to $(UTUNIT).exe)
    $(LINK) $(UTOBJSFULL) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(UTEXE)
```

It compiles all the object and profile files and links together a binary. However when i delete some profile file (gcno) and call "utbuild" again it won't re-compile to restore the .gcno file. It tries to do linking again because gcno is a prequisite to it, but it wont do the compiling.

I don't know how to name this case so couldn't find solution from internet. Basically one recipe creates two files and i don't know how to write the rule that re-run's recipe even when only one file needs to re-created.

I would appreciate some links or hints.

Comment: `$(UTOBJSGCNO): $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP)` tells make that *every* `.gcno` file has *every* `.o` file as a prerequisite. This almost certainly isn't what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes he is doing an overkill here, but that is not his question, as for his exact question, I think he just needs `;`.  Hard to test though being that it is a bit of a mess :)

Comment: the first 4 lines (some macro definitions) should use ':=' rather than '=' so the macro is only evaluated once.

Comment: This line: $(LINK) $(UTOBJSFULL) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(UTEXE) has a couple of problems: 1) the linker flags should be before the list of object files.  2) the list of object files (UTOBJSFULL) is not listed as a dependency in the target line

Comment: this rule: $(UTOBJS): %.o: %.c $(UTMAKEDEP) for the $(CC) line is not making use of the .dep file that was generated in the prior line.  in general, it would be better to have a rule to generate a specific dependency file that has a .c dependancy and a .h dependancy rather than generating the .dep file every time a file is to be compiled

Comment: This rule: $(UTOBJSGCNO): $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP) has no action (and is probably not a built-in rule) so no *.gcno file will be built

Comment: @user3629249 regarding your comment "This rule: $(UTOBJSGCNO): $(UTOBJS) $(UTMAKEDEP) has no action (and is probably not a built-in rule) so no *.gcno file will be built" - that is incorrect.  The  purpose of this rule is not to build the `.gcno` file.  The purpose of this rule is to capture the side effect of building the `.gcno` file by another rule recipe, without invoking that recipe multiple times.  Yes the rule is not entirely correct, as I show in my answer, `;` is necessary.  But that is a different problem.  The rule should in fact have a "no action" rule, that is correct.

Comment: @user3629249 regarding your comment "this rule: $(UTOBJS): %.o: %.c $(UTMAKEDEP) for the $(CC) line is not making use of the .dep file that was generated in the prior line"  - that is also incorrect comment.  The `$(CC)` line cannot possibly make use of the dependency file.  It is a compile line, and the compiler cannot use a dependency makefile.  It may be able to _produce_ one, that's true, but not utilize it.

Comment: Different types of linking flags have different positional requirements. Library search paths (I believe) need to be before libraries that need those paths and libraries need to be listed after the object files that need their symbols other options aren't positionally limited though to my knowledge. This is why make has both `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` for example.

Comment: @EtanReisner OK I deleted my previous comment, here is the new comment.

Comment: @user3629249 regarding your comment "1) the linker flags should be before the list of object files" - that is incorrect, some flags can be anywhere on the command line, and some, namely library flags, need to be _after_ the objects they are needed for.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the comments. I've tried no-op ";" and ":=" with same outcome.

I think i need to take one step back and explain why i asked this question. It's not just about deleting or not-deleting gcno files manually, it's about general understanding how to write such a Makefile which restores any missing or out-of-date file. My Makefile has similar cases in few places and it's using parallel build so when some file goes missing it gives lot of weird errors. Usually it's solved by "clean" and "all", but i'd like the Makefile to be perfect and handle the missing file issues nicely.

As the example above is not so clear without all the rest of the Makefile then i made a new simple test.

**hello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CCDIR    = C:\tools\MinGW
CCBINDIR = $(CCDIR)\bin
CCINCDIR = $(CCDIR)\include;$(CCDIR)\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include
CCLIBDIR = $(CCDIR)\lib;$(CCDIR)\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1

# Overcome "missing dll file" messages on Windows
CC       = set PATH=%PATH%;$(CCBINDIR)& $(CCBINDIR)\gcc.exe
LINK     = set PATH=%PATH%;$(CCBINDIR)& $(CCBINDIR)\gcc.exe

# Compile and link for code coverage
CFLAGS   = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -g3 -O0 $(addprefix -I,$(CCINCDIR))
LNKFLAGS = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -static -static-libgcc $(addprefix -L,$(CCLIBDIR))

OBJECTS  = hello.o
EXE      = hello.exe

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(subst /,\,$<) -o $@

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(EXE)

build: $(EXE)
```

"make build" creates following files:

- hello.o
- hello.gcno
- hello.exe

Now if i delete the "hello.gcno" and run build again it tells me:

```
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'build'.
```

The goal is to update Makefile so that the make re-creates the "hello.gcno". It would probably re-create "hello.o" and "hello.exe" also during that process but that's not a problem.

Edit:
Just to be clear: in real Makefile i really-really need the .gcno files. It's not just an additional information or something which to avoid or do optionally. The Makefile builds the unit test executables, runs them and executes gcov to generate code coverage information and gcovr creates a report of all the .gcov files. If .gcno file is missing it won't work. Also - as it's parallel build then dependencies shall be absolutely correct to avoid some process starting earlier and it's tricky because coverage report has dependencies coming from two "branches" - .gcno files from compile stage and .gcda files from execute stage. So that's why i need it to be correct.

Comment: why is this is a goal, to "restore any missing file"?  This is simply not a reasonable goal to have.  You need to treat the build as a "whole" not a collection of files.  The whole thing, all the files, directories, timestamps, that is your build.  If you corrupt your build, the correct remedy, is to `make clean` and start over.  The Makefile that can correct all the corruptions that may happen is not "correct" as you think, instead, it is "impossible".  Why do you want to "correct" some arbitrary subset of corruptions (missing files) while not correcting others?

Comment: The good way to think of a build is a "state machine" (not a finite one though).  The "states" are contents and timestamps of files. If you perform one of the allowed actions, the machine correctly chooses the new state.  What are the allowed actions?  Touching/editing/adding/deleting your sources, and `make` targets. That's it.  No deleting arbitrary files is allowed.

Comment: Ok, i see your point, but just out of interest - how do you explain the fact that when you delete an object file and then "make build" re-compiles it? Can you call it a side-effect or is it a normal behaviour?

Comment: Well, what I said, is, deletions of files are not allowed - in general.  If you do that, in general, bad things may happen and you may need to `make clean`.  That is to be expected.  Now, in practice, most of the time, if you delete some files, GNU Make will in fact correctly recover. In your case, delete `.o` file and the recovery is possible and easy.  Great, you are lucky :) Still, the correct way to handle this, if you must go about deleting files, is to have suitable "clean" targets for that, say `make clean_objects`.

Comment: I should also point out, that nowhere in the GNU Make manual, it says "Make will recover deleted files", or that such a behaviour is  recommended.  As with all software, if something is not specifically mentioned as supported, one should not assume it, no matter how "natural" or "works all the time for me" it may seem.

Comment: I was on vacation, but this topic is still in interest.
Leaving all rights & wrongs beside, what is the purely technical solution to this goal above?

Comment: Do you really need the static pattern rule `$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.c` for the compile command, i. e., do you need to restrict the targets that the rule applies to to `$(OBJECTS)`? (The solution would be straightforward for an implicit pattern rule.)

Comment: Regarding "deletions of files are not allowed" - this is in my opinion a lame excuse for writing broken makefiles, and it's good that you're not satisfied with that. The practice of `make clean && make all` causes excessive, unnecessary regeneration of files, which is exactly what `make` was designed to dispel; doing so is an abuse of `make`.

Answer (score 0):

your only option here is this :

(if you can change the rule)

```
$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
           $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(EXE)
```

to this:

```
%.exe %.gnco: $(OBJECTS)
           $(LINK) $(OBJECTS) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(EXE)
           $(GENERATE_GNCO) $<
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution of one thing dependig on two other things

```
compile:./src/main.c ./src/error.c
    gcc ./src/error.c ./src/main.c -o ./exe/calc
    

run : ./exe/calc
    ./exe/calc
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer in my opinion, is, don't delete any `.gcno` files by themselves.  If you have to "clean", use `make clean`, but don't just go about deleting files.

The "build" is a state machine, with all the files constituting a "state".  Don't corrupt the state!

Some people say, one should be able to delete arbitrary files and the build should recover.  My answer is, what about if you corrupt some `.o` file by hand, say, add some 0's and 1's, making it unusable (thank you user3629249 for pointing that needs to be clarified, that I am talking about corruption, not intentional editing).  Should the build also recover from that?  Obviously no - no build system in the world will recover if you touch the `.o` file this way.  Then why allow deleting a file, but not allow modifying it??  Where do you draw the line?

Simply put, any corruption should not be allowed.  Use `make clean` only, or better yet, write your Makefile properly, so you never need to clean period.

---

The whole Makefile has a number of problems, here is how it should look like (I am assuming this is on Windows/DOS):

```
.SUFFIXES:
UTEXE   := $(UTOBJSDIR)\$(UTUNIT).exe
UTOBJSFULL  := $(addprefix $(UTOBJSDIR)\,$(subst /,\, $(UTUUTSRC:.c=.o) $(UTUTSRC:.c=.o) $(UTCSRC:.c=.o)))
UTOBJSGCNO  := $(UTOBJSFULL:.o=.gcno)

.PHONY: utbuild all
all: utbuild
utbuild: $(UTEXE) $(UTOBJSGCNO) $(UTMAKEDEP)

$(UTOBJSGCNO): %.gcno: %.o $(UTMAKEDEP) ;

.SECONDARY: %\.
%\.: Makefile
    mkdir $*

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(UTOBJSFULL): $(UTOBJSDIR)\%.o: %.c $(UTMAKEDEP) | $$(@D)\.
    $(call report,Compiling $<)
    $(MKDEP) $(MKDFLAGS) -o.o -f$(UTOBJSDIR)\$(*F).dep $<
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(UTEXE): $(UTOBJSFULL) $(UTMAKEDEP) | $$(@D)\.
    $(call report,Linking to $(@F))
    $(LINK) $(UTOBJSFULL) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $@
```

Comment: I was just about to link to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27365859/258523 for reference for an answer here but then looking over your answer there it occurred to me that I think it has the exact problem he is running into here. It doesn't force a rebuild of the `$(UTOBJS)` file for the matching `$(UTOBJSGCNO)` file when only the `gcno` file has been deleted. Not to mention that this has every `gcno` file depend on *every* `.o` file (but that's a problem with the OPs makefile already.

Comment: Actually, after editing a .o file, a call to make should re-build the executable.  (editing a .o file is not that difficult, IF you know what your doing.  Back in the day, many many years ago, we used to do object file edits quite often as a full compile tied up the mainframe machine for way too long.

Comment: @user3629249  I agree with you.  You misunderstood my answer.  I do agree, that if you intentionally and correctly edit the `.o` file, you then want the build system to rebuild the library using that.   My answer was about something completely different.  Suppose you were to _corrupt_ the `.o` file making it unusable.  Maybe one should expect the build system to _recover_ from that, which means, rebuild the `.o` file correctly.  The answer is "no", one cannot expect that.  Similarly, one should not expect recovery from other state corruptions due to user negligence.

Comment: @user3629249 I clarified my answer based on your comment, thank you for pointing this out, needs to be clarified, that I meant "corrupting the .o file", not just any editing, not "correct editing".